# For loop for writing an excel file using xlsx?

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, xlsx, openxlsx

I am attempting to write an individual excel spreadsheet for STR_NBR you see in the data below

[image]

In other words the logic I think would look as follows:

```
for (i in seq_along(STR_NBR)) {
  openxlsx::write.xlsx("C:/Users/santi/Documents/R_Scripts/Export_Data_CSV.xlsx", 
                    output_file = sprintf("STR_NBR%s.xlsx", STR_NBR[i])
}
```

Basically, I am trying to create an individual spreadsheet for every STR_NBR

Example: Say I want to print a spreadsheet for every **type** column you see below.

```
  set.seed(42)  ## for sake of reproducibility
    n <- 6
    dat <- data.frame(id=1:n, 
                      date=seq.Date(as.Date("2020-12-26"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), "day"),
                      group=rep(LETTERS[1:2], n/2),
                      age=sample(18:30, n, replace=TRUE),
                      type=factor(paste("type", 1:n)),
                      x=rnorm(n))
    dat
    #   id       date group age   type         x
    # 1  1 2020-12-26     A  27 type 1 0.0356312
    # 2  2 2020-12-27     B  19 type 2 1.3149588
    # 3  3 2020-12-28     A  20 type 3 0.9781675
    # 4  4 2020-12-29     B  26 type 4 0.8817912
    # 5  5 2020-12-30     A  26 type 5 0.4822047
    # 6  6 2020-12-31     B  28 type 6 0.9657529
```

**Update with data from my actual data frame: I am trying to print out a new spreadsheet for every MVNDR column, but grouped not by every row**

```
Quote Date  eSVS Order Nbr  MVNDR
2021-05-24  H6328-206574    60710435
2021-05-27  H8926-157085    60710435
2021-05-24  H1020-178324    60660525
2021-05-24  H1020-178324    60660525
2021-05-27  H0772-64192 60074330
2021-05-27  H0772-64192 60074330
2021-05-27  H0772-64192 60074330
2021-05-25  H6646-240810    60063056
2021-05-25  H6646-240810    60063056
```

Comment: Can you provide us with some test data (rather than a screenshot) that we can copy and paste to better understand the issue and test possible solutions? You can share datasets with `dput(YOUR_DATASET)` or smaller samples with `dput(head(YOUR_DATASET))`. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#5963610) for detailed instructions.)

Comment: updated with an iris dataset

Comment: Can you give an example of what the output would look like? Would each spreadsheet just contain the row for the specified type?

Comment: It would just be the relevant columns and rows associated with the STR_NBR

Comment: @Jaskeil If the values in the MVNDR have `/` in them that could cause problems when trying to save the data.  Could you use dput on the dataframe and add the result to the question so I can replicate it and investigate further?

Comment: Sure, well we dont need to use that column. You can just use the number let me update the question.

Comment: I will try an update with dput as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `group_by` and `group_split` from the [dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) package to split the data and then use `write.xlsx` from the [xlsx](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/xlsx.pdf) package to create the Excel workbooks.

The following code uses your example data, you should be able to adjust it for your actual data.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(xlsx)

set.seed(42)  ## for sake of reproducibility
n <- 6
dat <- data.frame(id=1:n, 
                  date=seq.Date(as.Date("2020-12-26"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), "day"),
                  group=rep(LETTERS[1:2], n/2),
                  age=sample(18:30, n, replace=TRUE),
                  type=factor(paste("type", 1:n)),
                  x=rnorm(n))
dat
#   id       date group age   type         x
# 1  1 2020-12-26     A  27 type 1 0.0356312
# 2  2 2020-12-27     B  19 type 2 1.3149588
# 3  3 2020-12-28     A  20 type 3 0.9781675
# 4  4 2020-12-29     B  26 type 4 0.8817912
# 5  5 2020-12-30     A  26 type 5 0.4822047
# 6  6 2020-12-31     B  28 type 6 0.9657529

dat_grouped <- dat %>% group_by(type)

lapply(group_split(dat_grouped), function(x){write.xlsx(x,paste0(x$type, ".xlsx"))})
```

Comment: When I applied to my data frame I had the following issue:

Comment: `Error in saveWorkbook(wb, file, password = password) : 
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (type == "xls") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (type == "xlsx") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: What code is giving the error? Is there anything 'different' about the data?

Comment: Thanks for the response, the code is the following: `lapply(group_split(d22_open_quotes), function(x){write.xlsx(x,paste0(x$MVNDR, ".xlsx"))})` where I attempt to print out a new spreadsheet for every mvndr. Let me also update the question wth a data frame

Comment: I reframed the question so that it is more clear and the desired output is more clear as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67873269/iterating-over-large-dataframe-to-write-individual-excel-spreadsheets