# Iterating over large dataframe to write individual Excel spreadsheets

Tags: r, excel, loops, for-loop, apply

I want to write unique spreadsheets based on the MVNDR number you see below

**Current Data Strucutre/Data Frame**

```
 Quote Date  eSVS Order Nbr  MVNDR     Name 
    2021-05-24  H6328-206574    60710435  Joe
    2021-05-27  H8926-157085    60710435  Joe 
    2021-05-24  H6328-206574    60710435  Carl
    2021-05-27  H8926-157085    60710435  Carl
    2021-05-24  H6328-206574    60710435 John
    2021-05-27  H8926-157085    60710435 John
```

**Desired Output in a Unique Spreadsheet**

***Spreadsheet1* & Desired Path Name: C:\Users\santi\Documents\R_Scripts\MVNDR_Joe**

```
Quote Date  eSVS Order Nbr  MVNDR     Name 
2021-05-24  H6328-206574    60710435  Joe
2021-05-27  H8926-157085    60710435  Joe
```

***Spreadsheet2* & Desired Path Name: C:\Users\santi\Documents\R_Scripts\MVNDR_John**

```
Quote Date  eSVS Order Nbr  MVNDR    Name 
2021-05-24  H6328-206574    60710435 John
2021-05-27  H8926-157085    60710435 John
```

***Spreadsheet3* & Desired Path Name: C:\Users\santi\Documents\R_Scripts\MVNDR_Carl**

```
Quote Date  eSVS Order Nbr  MVNDR    Name 
2021-05-24  H6328-206574    60710435  Carl
2021-05-27  H8926-157085    60710435  Carl
```

Comment: That is my question but I felt like I asked it poorly so I wanted to recreate the question

Comment: Do you now want to group on name?

Comment: Yes, I would like to group by that or MVNDR works as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found what the problem is, and I should have spotted it earlier.

Since there's now more than one record for each group `x$Name` returns a vector with the name repeated for each record.

We only need the name and we can easily extract that.

Here's the updated code.

```
library(dplyr)
library(xlsx)

dat <- read.csv('data.csv')

dat_grouped <- dat %>% group_by(Name)

lapply(group_split(dat_grouped), function(x){write.xlsx(x, paste0(x$Name[1], ".xlsx"))})
```

Comment: Thanks I am hoping this works if I can figure out some minor issues I would imagine. I received this error,  is this related to my machine? `Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
In addition: Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: MVNDR_NBR` This is after running `lapply(group_split(dat_grouped), function(x){write.xlsx(x, paste0(x$MVNDR_NBR[1], ".xlsx"))})`

Comment: That looks like there is no column named 'MVNDR_NBR', so the first thing you should do is check the column names in the data you've imported.

Comment: ahh yeah that was part of the issue. Here is the final output and I got it to work ! `dat_grouped22 <- d22_open_quotes %>% group_by(MVNDR_NBR)

#Logic to Print it Out 
lapply(group_split(dat_grouped22), function(x){openxlsx::write.xlsx(x, paste0(x$MVNDR_NBR[1], ".xlsx"))`